# Replace list of list according to second list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Given

```
p = {{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {11, 0}}
```

I want to replace parts according to a second list `t1` if the first part is equal but the second part different (first parts in `t1` always match first parts in `p`)

```
t1 = {{5, 1}, {11, 1}}
```

Which would give me

```
{{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}
```

I can do it by

```
t2 = t1[[All, 1]];
t3 = Flatten[Position[p[[All, 1]], #] & /@ t2];
p[[t3]] = t1;
p
```

Any ideas for smarter ways (like `Replace`, `ReplacePart`, `ReplaceList` or `Cases`?

Comment: Does `Fold[Replace[#1, {#2[[1]], _} -> #2, {1}] &, p, t1]` works for you ?

Comment: Yes,it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = Values @ GroupBy[Join @ ##, First, Last] &;

f[p, t1]
```

> ```
> {{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Good solution! Great idea!

Answer (score 7):

```
☺ = # /. ({#, _} -> {##} & @@@ #2) &;

p ~ ☺ ~ t1
```

> ```
> {{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
pos = Position[p[[All, 1]], #] & /@ First /@ t1
```

> {{{4}}, {{6}}}

```
ReplacePart[p, Thread[pos -> t1]]
```

> {{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different `p2` to include duplicates/same `t1`:

```
p2 = {{2, 0}, {11, 3}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {11, 0}}
t1 = {{5, 1}, {11, 1}}
```

Create a list of rules:

```
t2 = Replace[t1, {x_, y_} :> {x, Blank[]}, {1}]
rules = MapThread[Rule, {t2, t1}
```

> `{{5, _}, {11, _}}`
>
> `{{5, _} -> {5, 1}, {11, _} -> {11, 1}}`

Apply rules:

```
p2 /. rules
```

> {{2, 0}, {11, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}

I think this is more easily modifiable than my other approach.

Comment: Very Good! I like your idea!

Answer (score 2):

```
 List @@@ Normal[<|Rule @@@ p, Rule @@@ t1|>]
```

{{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}

Comment: (+1) Nice, @eldo!

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
p /. Thread[Cases[#, {x_, _} :> {x, _}] -> #] &@t1

(*{{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {8, 0}, {11, 1}}*)
```